# Web API, call process asynchronously from controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need to call a process from my Web API controller action asynchronously so the action doesn't wait for the process to finish to return.  How is this done?  I'm trying to avoid writing a message queue.

This is an example of what I am looking to do

```
 public JsonResult Index(string key)
 {
     //call some process here but don't wait for it to finish, 
     //this would be something like logging or sending an email

     // this returns immediately
     return new JsonResult
     {
        ...
      };

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Task.Run()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx)  or [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem(v=vs.110).aspx)

For logging you might want to write an asynchronous log appender, if using log4net. For email, I would consider using a drop directory and having the SMTP server pick up the mail asynchronously. Both of these would remove the complexity from the controller action and localize it in the component you're using instead.

Comment: Those were the solutions I was looking at.  This article says that they might not always work.  http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html   Maybe it's the best solution without relying on external queuing?

Comment: I wouldn't do it for a long running task only something that is relatively quick.  If you have long running tasks that you need an early return from I'd use a Service Bus.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to lose your background work, you can use `Task.Run()`. If it is important, use `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`. For more info, take a look at this.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Great information thanks.  I wasn't aware of `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`.  The article also has good information for using Azure which I was considering.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at background job schedulers like [hangfire](http://hangfire.io) or [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net)

Below is a nice blog entry on these solutions.

[How to run Background Tasks in ASP.Net](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)